# How to make a quick push ignoring unfinished work?

Tags: git

I have pulled from the central repository and made a lot of changes to one of the files. I am not done with my changes yet (it is a "work in progress" and I plan to finish my work in few days).

Now, I have noticed a bug in the code. It is just one line of the code that has to be corrected and it needs to be done urgently.

I can correct the line but I cannot push back to the repository because I am not yet done with the remaining changes.

What should I do if I want to push just the line form which the bug is removed? The rest of changes I plan to push in few days.

Answer (score 2):

You could stash your changes, make the necessary fix for the bug, push it and then unstash your changes to get back your old work which was half done.

Refer to [this manual page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

Answer (score 2):

You can stash your current changes. Say for example, you've changed three files named `test1.txt`, `test2.txt` and `test3.txt`.

Now, since you found a bug in `test1.txt`, but you've some changes made already in all the three files, so you should stash them first using

```
git stash
```

Now, make the necessary changes you want and merge it into master. Once done, pop out the changes back using

```
git stash pop
```

Here, all your changes will be back in the working directory. Note that if you have made a change on the same line which you've stashed, it will result in merge conflict, hence, you need to select the change of `master` branch and remove the changes made in your local branch.

---

Practical steps

```
#currently in wip branch

modified test1.txt
modified test2.txt
modified test3.txt

git stash #stashes all the above files

#you now add your fix to test1.txt

git add test1.txt
git commit -m 'hotfix'
git checkout master
git merge wip
git push origin master
git checkout wip

#brings back your stashed changes
git stash pop

#here, it will raise a merge conflict if you just pushed a fix
#on the same line you had stashed else, it will merge straight away
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one particular file.

At first make sure you stash the changes you made in the files and then

```
git add only/one/file.c 
git commit -m "Hot_fix"
```

here you can cherry-pick your commit or you can merge your branch to master.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier than stashing your changes and making the change again would be to do a partial add of the file in question. Run:

```
git add -p myfile.txt
```

This will step you through each chunk of changes, asking if you want to add stage them or not. Use `n` for no and `y` for yes. Once you've used `y` on the one line you need now, use `q` to quit the interactive adding interface.

Then you can commit and push as you normally would without losing the remaining changes.